# How to avoid a lengthy computation and speed up debugging in Python, VScode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

I want to be able to save and restore the state during debugging in VScode. There is a lengthy computation before the function I want to debug and it takes a long time to reach the breakpoint Im interested in due to the lengthy computation.

One option would be to manually save all the objects that the function Im interested in needs and create a separate script that would start by the loading statement and continued as the original program but I doubt this is the correct solution. I fell like this functionality is already there, only I dont know about it. How do professional devs cope with this?

Comment: look at the pickle module, you can save and restore the value of variables

Comment: I got: Can't pickle local object 'Loader._recreate_base_user_object.<locals>._UserObject'. I made the variables gloal but it didnt help. Seems like pickle is helpful but in more simple cases.

Comment: show example code of what you try to do

Comment: There's also [Dill](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill) that extends `pickle`. And I don't think you'd want to start by serializing or storing everything, just the object that that was computationally expensive. Get that working first so you can focus on what is limiting in regards to your real needs. Always start small. Then if that works, you can try extending. Have you looked into  the `%store` magic? See [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/extensions/storemagic.html). I bring that up because below MingJie-MSFT is suggesting Jupyter. Not applicable for your actual OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

A feasible solution is to use Jupyter-Notebook. After running the content that needs to be cached, you can repeatedly debug some functions.

The advantage is that it can be run repeatedly in a short period of time. The disadvantage is that after restarting vscode or the jupyter kernel, previously run cells still need to be run again.